# Exception trying to convert String to UTC date format

Tags: java, date

I tried to convert the string date to UTC date with below Java code snippet but getting Unparseable date format exception. Please find the code below and help me fix this issue.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-SSSZ");
    String strDate= "2017-06-01T01:30-0400";
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        date = new Date(formatter.format(date));
        System.out.println(date+"gmt");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ`. There are no milliseconds in your string.

Comment: The `-0400` is the UTC offset, not the seconds, so your pattern should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ`

Comment: FYI, the `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes are part of the troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-06-01T01:30-0400" ).toInstant()`  Actually a tiny bug will bite when parsing that string with an offset-from-UTC lacking the optional colon character between hours and minutes. Either add the colon or define a formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter`. Bug fixed in Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot parse the

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-SSSZ"
```

Becuase of did not match with your

```
strDate= "2017-06-01T01:30-0400"
```

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-SSS'Z'");
String strDate= "2017-06-01T01:30-040Z";
```

Comment: FYI, the `SimpleDateFormat` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-06-01T01:30-0400" )`

Comment: Oh thank you for mentioning.

Comment: Actually a tiny bug will bite when parsing that string with an offset-from-UTC lacking the optional colon character between hours and minutes. Either add the colon or define a formatting pattern. Bug fixed in Java 9.